# Angular sources with REST services for both: web app and electron

Tags: angular, electron

we thought about packing our existing angluar web app in an electron project, to run it offline.
Up to now, the web app loads a configuration by REST requests. In the electron app, this information should located in a local file.

Any recommendations how this can be done efficiently?

My first Idea, mocking the backend in an *express* server in electron doesn't seem pretty common. 
But redirecting all REST requests in angular also doesn't seem straigt forward to me.

Comment: oh yeah absolutely. i also have an angular web app that i run offline as well. throw the REST api in electron, and validate your api routes on the frontend to check which api to send to

Answer (score 0):

So what I would do is create an Http extension class, and update the endpoint based on a parameter you send through the http request.

Http Extender:

```
export function HttpAuthCreator(http: HttpClient) {
return new HttpAuth(http)
}

@Injectable()
export class HttpAuth {
// Extending the HttpClient through the Angular DI.
public constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
// If you don't want to use the extended versions in some cases you can access 
the public property and use the original one.
// for ex. this.httpClient.http.get(...)
}

/**
 * GET request
 * @param string endPoint it doesn't need / in front of the end point
 * @param IRequestOptions options options of the request like headers, body, etc.
 * @returns Observable<T>
*/
public get<T>(endPoint: string, destination?: string, options?: IRequestOptions): Observable<T> {
return this.http.get<T>(
  this.updateEndpoint(endPoint, destination),
  this.configRequestOptions(options, destination)
)
}
```

And then your subroutine to update the endpoint

```
private updateEndpoint(endpoint: string, destination?: string) {
if (destination === 'local') {
  return `${environment.localAPI}${endpoint}`
} else {
  return `${environment.onlineAPI}${endpoint}`
}
}
```

This way you can dynamically handle your endpoints locations

```
  get() {
return this.http.get(`/organizations/${params.id}`, 'local').toPromise()
}
```